# c# UWP Webview inside Scrollviewer only not working on Mobile

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, scrollviewer

Got a weird one; I'm using a webview inside of a scrollviewer (so I can have a stackpanel above the webview that scrolls with it) and my solution works fine on desktop PC and tablet (using both mouse AND touch) but for some reason, on a mobile phone the page just wont scroll! No idea why. Here is what I have done:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="theScrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <WebView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                 Margin="0" x:Name="theWebView" 
                 Height="2000"
                 DefaultBackgroundColor="#ff2E2E2E" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>    
</ScrollViewer>
```

and to stop the scrolling in the webview I have added the following to the CSS loaded into the webview:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y: hidden
```

The height property of the webview wont stay 2000; but I know for content in a scrollviewer to scroll it needs a height property. Anyway this works perfectly with mouse and touch on PCs and tablets, but on Windows 10 Mobile it just doesn't scroll.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway this works perfectly with mouse and touch on PCs and tablets, but on Windows 10 Mobile it just doesn't scroll.

I think the problem is that your `Webview` will not pass the manipulation events to its parent `ScrollViewer`.

On PC, we can scroll the `ScrollViewer` by dragging `Thumb` in the `ScrollBar` or rolling the wheel of mouse, these two interactions can be detected by `ScrollViewer`.

But when on mobile, we can only scroll the `ScrollViewer` by swiping the content area inside the `ScrollViewer`, since your `WebView` fill the whole content of `ScrollViewer`, the swiping gesture will be caught by `WebView` firstly and not handle to `ScrollViewer` again, and now your `WebView` has enough height to hold the web content, the default scroll-function of `WebView` will also not work.

Here is a suggestion: Give a smaller `Width` to `WebView` when it works on mobile, and you can scroll the `ScrollViewer` by swiping on the blank area. But I think this is not a graceful solution to your problem, this will possible make the layout become ugly.

Another suggestion is that you can try to create your own `Thumb` in the right side of your `StackPanel` and `WebView` inside the `ScrollViewer` for scrolling, make this `Thumb` slid-able and programatically make the `ScrollViewer` scrolled when the `Thumb` is translated.